# Lookup 2 values in a table and write to a 3rd cell in the table

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table that has duplicate text values in each column that I need to write a value to.

I am using a form with 3 input boxes that are used to set the criteria to lookup and write a new value to.

I want to find the matching row based on the values on the form and write the new value to a cell.

My problem is, I can't figure out how to find the matching row using vba.

I've tried different things (index, match, vlookup) but just can't seem to get it figured out.

The picture below shows what I have now.

I need to update the QTY column in the table with the form's Coin Quantity value based off of the Exchange and Currency selected on the form.

So, in this case, I need to change Binance ETH Qty from 7 to 6.5

[Form And Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o79kN.jpg)

Thanks for any help!

---I've adjusted Courtney's answer below with the following:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Data")

     
For Row = 2 To 50
    Col = 14
      If (ws.Cells(Row, Col) = ExchangeInputValue) And (ws.Cells(Row, Col + 1) = CurrencyInputValue) Then
        'UpdateQty
        'UpdateQty = boxQty.Value
        'Qty = boxQty.Value
        'UpdateQty.Value = boxQty.Value
        'ws.Cells(Col + 2).Value = boxQty.Value
        
      End If
Next Row
```

But nothing selects the Qty column based on the form inputs.

Comment: Loop over the table and compare the relevant cells to your two form values.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to do a nested Vlookup or Index if you wanted to go those routes.  Or you can just loop through each row with an if statement:

```
For row = start to finish
    If (ws.cells(row,col) = ExchangeInputValue) and (ws.cells(row,col+1) = CurrencyInputValue) then
        UpdateQTY
    End if
Next row
```